# Percona cluster behaving weird

Tags: database, percona

I have 2 servers, both are identical on hardware and software.

I have installed Percona XtraDB Cluster latest version. Raised the cluster.

Wsrep reported everything fine, both nodes were connected.

Created test database on node1, instantly synced to node2.

It looked like everything is working fine.

However.

I created base DATA on node 1, imported mysq base via mysqldump from other server in it.

Website was working fine, looked like everything was succesfully completed.

But then I noticed something interested.

Size of database on node1 was 150 MB  while on node2 was 147mb.

I checked and some tables were indeed empty.

And now comes very interesting part.

If I manually import data into base on node2 (this one was 147 MB) size becomes 150MB. BUT then the base on node 1 goes down to 147MB.

So any idea why is this happening?  Why will one node always have smaller databases by 3mb, not the same node mind you. That will depend on which node we are going to import data into databases.

So in short if I import on node1 then node2 will be 3 MB short, and vice versa.

Anyone ever had similar issue and might give me nudge in right direction? 
Logs don't see anything weird or errors.

ps..
I asked on percona forum also but there are like 90% of topics there unanswered so I dont have much hope for response there.

Answer (score 0):

Think I found the solution.

Percona cluster can't replicate tables with myisam engine. It will only replicate and work tables with innodb engine.

Answer (score 0):

A bit old question but what might interest you is that you can try some experimental replication of MyIsam:

> The following limitations apply to Percona XtraDB Cluster:
>   • Replication works only with InnoDB storage engine. Any writes to tables of other types, including system
>   (mysql.*) tables, are not replicated. However, DDL statements are replicated in statement level, and changes
>   to mysql.* tables will get replicated that way. So you can safely issue CREATE USER..., but issuing
>   INSERT INTO mysql.user... will not be replicated. You can enable experimental MyISAM replication
>   support using the wsrep_replicate_myisam variable.

Taken from official [documentation](https://learn.percona.com/hubfs/Manuals/Percona_XtraDB_Cluster/PXC-5.7/Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-5.7.16-27.19.pdf?utm_campaign=Manual%202016%3A%20Percona%20XtraDB%20Cluster%205.7%20--%208.11.16&utm_source=hs_automation&utm_medium=email&utm_content=39349248&_hsenc=p2ANqtz-9kyNvTrqNiCAlzhceNytIYTbYIzCmvh9qd-nAAn5oNd6vX3St-WKHVE7Q3UCFI1tX0Pva5JGzJo07GQ_QBE_ZTFb_o0A&_hsmi=39349248)

I didn't try it because we're running on InnoDB but it might be helpful for someone reading this post nowadays/in future